# SQL,Trying to get the sum with a datetime column

Tags: sql

I have 2 columns, one is showing the email and the other one shows the date the email was created.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
registered customer     4     Date 01-01-2018
registered customer     2     Date 01-02-2018   
registered customer     9     Date 01-03-2018
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you have two rows for the same email? One for the email value and one for when the email was created??

Comment: No, I have 1 row for the email only
 
email  123@hotmail.com  date: january 01, 2018
email  abc@hotmail.com          date: january 01, 2018

I wan to show this

email 2 date january 01, 2018

Comment: @RyanWilson i think he means 2 column, email and created_at. But i'm may be wrong

Comment: try to group by date with count aggrigate function in select

Comment: @Maxim Yeah, I'm not sure from the post which it is. If it is two rows for the same email I'd restructure the table. And have column for email and column for CreationDate.

Comment: yes 2 columns email and createdDate I`m trying to knpow how many email for each days was created.

Comment: @StandleyStEloy Attach table stucture and mock data for the table and expected ouput

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If table stucture consist of 2 columns(email, created_at) you should groupping your data by created_at field.
Example:

```
   select date, count(email) as count 
   from your_table 
   group by date
```

Answer (score 1):

You appears to want :

```
select date, count(email) as emailcount
from table t
group by date;
```

**EDIT :** Use `count()` instead of `sum()` & if you want to count day wise email as registered customer then use the date in `GROUP BY` clause instead of doing *aggregation*.

```
SELECT SITEID, THEDATE, COUNT(EMAIL) 
FROM [database].[dbo].[table] 
WHERE LOGIN NOT LIKE '' AND SITEID = 'someSiteId' AND 
      THEDATE >= '2017-01-01' 
GROUP BY SITEID, THEDATE
ORDER BY THEDATE ASC;
```

Comment: I don`t think that`s going to work and the error I always get is `Operand data type varchar is invalid form sum operator`

Comment: @StandleyStEloy. . . No relation between an error message as you said and the preceding query. Something wrong with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many entries you have, you could also do:

```
Select Num, date
FROM table
ORDER BY date
```

Then make Num be an identity column in the table that matches the email with a customer number. Maybe not as ideal depending on your data...but if you are referring to the customer by their number you may potentially want that info in the table.

Comment: Didn`t work unfortunately, I would like the email field to become an integer with a number and the date fiel to be only one time like I have 5 emails on january 1st, followe by 2 emails on january 2nd etc

Comment: SELECT
 SITEID,
 EMAIL,
 SUM(THEDATE)
FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
WHERE LOGIN NOT LIKE '' AND SITEID = 'someSiteId' AND THEDATE >= '2017-01-01' 
GROUP BY THEDATE
ORDER BY THEDATE ASC

Comment: something like that I`m trying to accomplish telling me 2 emails created january 1st,   3 emails cretated january 2nd,    0 email created on january 3rd.

Comment: Select Date, count(*)
FROM table
Group by Date